# Using optional parameters for Postgress Go query

Tags: postgresql, go

So I want to create a query function that can filter by status and/or paymentType....I am checking to see if the parameter is empty and if not I assigned it to a value, but I am getting the follwoing error:

`Error executing query: pq: could not determine data type of parameter $1`

I am not sure where is the problem, as I see it it shouldn't even be calling parameter 1 if it's empty

```
func getDatabaseTransactions(page int, pageSize int, status string, paymentType string) []transaction {
    if db == nil {
        createConnection()
    }

    offset := (page - 1) * pageSize
    query := "SELECT id, amount, currency, status, payment_type, created_at, updated_at FROM transactions WHERE 1=1"
    var transactions []transaction

    log.Printf("valor status: %v\n", status)
    args := []interface{}{}
    if status != "" {
        query += " AND status = $1 "
        args = append(args, status)
    }

    if paymentType != "" {
        query += " AND payment_type =  ANY($2) "
        args = append(args, pq.Array([]string{paymentType}))
}

    query += " ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT $3  OFFSET  $4 "
    args = append(args, pageSize, offset)

    rows, err := db.Query(query, args...)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error executing query: %v\n", err)
        return nil
    }
```

I am leaving the two options I tried - in argument 1 and 2 - without sucesse.

Comment: There's a problem with your logic. If `status` is empty but `paymentType` is not then your query parameters will start with `$2` but the corresponding `[]string{paymentType}` argument will be at position 1.

Comment: instead of `$1` `$2` and so on,  you'll have to use `len(args)+1`

Comment: Another problem is that a parameter placeholder when passed to `ANY` requires an explicit type cast, otherwise the type checker will complain with the error you've cited. In other words it should be `ANY($2::T[])` (where `T` is the type of the payment_type column).